# UIImage resize aspect fill and crop

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have this code, I take a photo with this size  2448x3264 and i need resize and adjust to display of screen at the top left. sorry for my english thanks

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{

    imagenUsr = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    NSLog(@"%f",imagenUsr.size.height);   //2448px
    NSLog(@"%f",imagenUsr.size.width);   //3264px


}
```

I need adjust to 320x568 aspect to fill at the top and left of the image taken

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    imagenUsr = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    double width = imagenUsr.size.width;
    double height = imagenUsr.size.height;
    double screenWidth = self.view.frame.size.width;
    double apect = width/height;
    double nHeight = screenWidth/ apect;
    self.imgView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, screenWidth, nHeight);
    self.imgView.center = self.view.center;
    self.imgView.image = imagenUsr;
}
```

This will help you keeping the aspect ratio as before.

Another way would be:

```
self.imgView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
self.imgView.image = imagenUsr;
```

Hope this helps.. :)

Comment: This was perfect! Thanks!

Comment: @simon > Welcome. Happy to help!

Answer (score 15):

Swift 3.0 / 4.0

AspectFill image cropping/Resizing... according to UIImageview Frame Size.

```
    func ResizeImage(with image: UIImage?, scaledToFill size: CGSize) -> UIImage? {
    let scale: CGFloat = max(size.width / (image?.size.width ?? 0.0), size.height / (image?.size.height ?? 0.0))
    let width: CGFloat = (image?.size.width ?? 0.0) * scale
    let height: CGFloat = (image?.size.height ?? 0.0) * scale
    let imageRect = CGRect(x: (size.width - width) / 2.0, y: (size.height - height) / 2.0, width: width, height: height)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size, false, 0)
    image?.draw(in: imageRect)
    let newImage: UIImage? = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Comment: This does a pretty good job! (Except the naming, it is not very Swifty) :)

Comment: Also, there is a possible divide-by-zero issue if the passed image is nil :)

Answer (score 3):

EDIT: Not sure if I missed this or it was edited, but I didn't see that you wanted to crop it as well. Rashad's solution should work for you.

Have you tried creating an image view with the image and adding it to the view?

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    imagenUsr = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    imageView.image = imagenUsr;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    [self.view addSubview:imageView];
}
```