# Ios :the image is not appearing properly in uiimage when its size is larger or smaller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

i have `uimage` of screen size and in my application the image is coming from server so its size may be larger or smaller. so when i fit it into uimageimage its looking very bad. i have tried `UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit` but the image is showing in rectangle shape. Is there any way to display my image in `uimage` properly without being stretch ?

Comment: Are you sure the image is correct? Aspect fit doesn't stretch.

Comment: try using UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill it will maintain aspect ratio,irrespective the image size

Comment: thank you munu but uiviewcontectscaleAspectFill is not working its showing opnly half of the image.

Answer (score 1):

Try AspectFill, it could solve the problem.

Comment: As written here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478627/uiimage-resize-aspect-fill-and-crop [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25478627/uiimage-resize-aspect-fill-and-crop)